# LINQ queries to generate a report on accrued work time on projects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

The following code fetches data from a MySql database to generate a simple report on accrued work time on projects.

I've been away from Entity Framework for a while and looking at this code you can see that the creation of `ListProject` is basically repeated 3 times.

Is there any way to refactor this so I can reuse the duplicate parts?

I've thought about a factory method, but that won't work because it can't be translated to SQL by the expression interpreter.

```cs
    var project = entities.Tickets
        .Where(p => p.ID == id)
        .Select(p => new ListProject
        {
            Id = p.ID,
            Name = p.ueberschrift,
            AssignedEmployee = new ListEmployee
            {
                Id = p.AssignedEmployee.ID,
                Name = p.AssignedEmployee.name
            },
            WorkUnits = p.WorkUnits
                .Select(wu => new ListProjectWorkUnit
                {
                    Duration = wu.dauer,
                    PauseDuration = wu.pauseDauer,
                    Employee = new ListEmployee
                    {
                        Id = wu.AssignedEmployee.ID,
                        Name = wu.AssignedEmployee.name
                    }
                })
                .ToList()
            })
            .Single();
```

```cs
    project.Tickets = entities.Tickets
        .Where(p => p.vonProjekt == id)
        .Where(p => p.phaseID == 0)
        .OrderBy(p => p.ueberschrift)
        .Select(p => new ListProject
        {
            Id = p.ID,
            Name = p.ueberschrift,
            AssignedEmployee = new ListEmployee
            {
                Id = p.AssignedEmployee.ID,
                Name = p.AssignedEmployee.name
            },
            WorkUnits = p.WorkUnits
                .Select(wu => new ListProjectWorkUnit
                {
                    Duration = wu.dauer,
                    PauseDuration = wu.pauseDauer,
                    Employee = new ListEmployee
                    {
                        Id = wu.AssignedEmployee.ID,
                        Name = wu.AssignedEmployee.name
                    }
                })
                .ToList()
        })
        .ToList();
```

```cs
    project.Phases = entities.projekt_phase
        .Where(p => p.projektID == id)
        .OrderBy(p => p.rang)
        .Select(p => new ListProjectPhase
        {
            Id = p.ID,
            Name = p.name,
            Tickets = p.Tickets
                .OrderBy(t => t.ueberschrift)
                .Select(t => new ListProject
                {
                    Name = t.ueberschrift,
                    Id = t.ID,
                    AssignedEmployee = new ListEmployee
                    {
                        Id = t.AssignedEmployee.ID,
                        Name = t.AssignedEmployee.name
                    },
                    WorkUnits = t.WorkUnits
                        .Select(wu => new ListProjectWorkUnit
                        {
                            Duration = wu.dauer,
                            PauseDuration = wu.pauseDauer,
                            Employee = new ListEmployee
                            {
                                Id = wu.AssignedEmployee.ID,
                                Name = wu.AssignedEmployee.name
                            }
                        })
                        .ToList()
                })
                .ToList()
        })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation, it would help with the review :)

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Mast I understand, but I tried to correct a copy pasta error. One of those `.Single()`s is a `.ToList()` in production code.

Comment: Well, next time do it right the first time and please take a look at the [help/on-topic]. We take answer invalidation quite seriously here and people reviewing different versions of the same code in the same question gets very messy very fast.

Answer (score 1):

> I've thought about a factory method, but that won't work because it
>   can't be translated to SQL by the expression interpreter.

Why don't you call (as suggested by t3chb0t) `AsEnumerable()` right before your factory method? You would perform the factory method in memory.

```
 var project = entities.Tickets
        .Where(p => p.ID == id)
        .AsEnumerable()   // <-- loads the tickets into memory
        .Select(p => myFactoryMethod(p))
        .Single();
```

Comment: Thanks, I've thought about that, but I would need a bunch of `.Include`s to get all the nested information I need. Plus I don't want to have all the content of these tables in memory as they're a bit meaty.

Comment: @w4n then have you thought about making a view and mapping this with EF?

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't our data base. This is a ticketing system to which we only have read access.

Comment: @w4n I remember back in the day that we also had some boiler-plate code with Includes. But we managed to put this in reusable code blocks deep in our repositories. I don't have any examples of this code available anymore. Do you think when going the Include path, you still need to duplicate your code?

Comment: I think the preferred way is to use the `.AsEnumerable()` extension instead of `ToList`, I'm not sure but my gut tells me that it would then loop over the result only once. At least this is what I'm always doing...

Comment: @t3chb0t I think you might be right. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968469/whats-the-differences-between-tolist-asenumerable-asqueryable

Answer (score 0):

I can't check this with a compiler right now but general idea is that you can benefit from [IQueryable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable-1?view=netframework-4.8).
Define method like this

```
IQueryable<ListProject> SelectListProjects(IQueryable<Tickets> tickets) 
{
    return entities.Tickets
        .Where(p => p.vonProjekt == id)
        .Where(p => p.phaseID == 0)
        .OrderBy(p => p.ueberschrift)
        .Select(p => new ListProject
        {
            Id = p.ID,
            Name = p.ueberschrift,
            AssignedEmployee = new ListEmployee
            {
                Id = p.AssignedEmployee.ID,
                Name = p.AssignedEmployee.name
            },
            WorkUnits = p.WorkUnits
                .Select(wu => new ListProjectWorkUnit
                {
                    Duration = wu.dauer,
                    PauseDuration = wu.pauseDauer,
                    Employee = new ListEmployee
                    {
                        Id = wu.AssignedEmployee.ID,
                        Name = wu.AssignedEmployee.name
                    }
                })
                .ToList()
            });            
}
```

and use it as follows

```
var project = SelectListProjects(entities.Tickets
        .Where(p => p.ID == id)).Single();
```